# Make an answered question

Tags: discussion, answered-questions, grub

Recently I answered [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868148/upgrade-from-windows-7-to-8-1-alongside-ubuntu/) I explain a step-by-step "guide" for   grub install and grub boot error

Since Ask Ubuntu doesn't have documentation like Stack Overflow's I was interested in making an answered question. Would this be helpful in the future? If yes, should I make the question as a Community Wiki or not?

Comment: It's a not uncommon practice to post a question and your own solution to it.   Feel free to do so.

Comment: @Serg thank you I will , but post it as a community wiki or not ?

Comment: @Kain well, let me ask you this first: are you trying to post the same contents of the answer you linked  into new post ? Because there's no purpose in duplicating the contents.  As for community wiki . . . it's up to you.

Comment: @Serg I think understand the Community wiki a bit more now , so if I write a unique staff , it will be helpful else it will be a duplicated content , right ?

Comment: Yeah, so if I see question say "How to upgrade Windows while keeping Ubuntu" , I'll have to vote it as duplicate of the one you linked.  You can ask moderator to convert  the one you linked into community wiki, but they will need to decide if that question deserves canonical status. I'd personally say,  just leave it for now. That question is good on its own

Comment: @Serg okay I will leave it , it will grow automatically by time ; a "stupid" question how to ask a moderator ?

Comment: @Kain you can do so either here, on meta, or in [AskUbuntu chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room). You need 20 reputation to access chat, which I see you already have. Look for users with diamond next to their user name

Comment: @Serg okay thank you for your time .

Comment: You do not need a moderator to help you convert an answer to a community wiki, you can just click the edit button, and check the box "make community wiki" to the right below the text box. Only mods can convert **questions** to community wikis. To add to what @Serg has said, please do not post a new question in order to re-post the same answer again. In general though, as the linked post says, it's fine to post a Q&A if it's not a duplicate, and you aren't obliged to make such posts community wikis

Comment: @Zanna I was talking about both answer and question, and naturally mod would be needed for question. If the goal is to have canonical question, then community wiki question would be preferred. Hope my meaning is clearer. Sorry. Can't talk today at all

Comment: @Zanna yea I understand that , thank you too